# Angular $filter not filtering specific number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the below filter setup, it works fine until I have similar data sets.

```
$filter('filter')($rootScope.Items, {line: 7});
```

This will include line 17 and 27 and so on. I assume this will happen to other numbers as well. Is there a way to specifically filter out the correct number?

Comment: is explained in docs ... look at `comparator` argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should filter it by having strict comparator, by specifying `true` as 3rd parameter of filter.

```
$filter('filter')($rootScope.Items, {line: 7}, true)
```